# form submit message appearing twice

Tags: magento-1.8, contact-us

I have included contact us form in cms page using below code

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

But after doing this, message after submitting the form is coming twice.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PScwj.png]

How this can be rectified? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
```

This is inside the `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/contacts/form.phtml` So the messages are just `echo'ed` twice. Either remove the standard message block from the layout or remove the above from the template. I think editing the template is easier.

Comment: Thanks Fabian, but I also need to know if it is a bug or a process in including contact us block in cms page. I guess it is in process, am I correct?

Comment: The contact form is normally added via layout.xml to the page and no extra message block. I don't know, why this is implemented this way, if you ask me, this doesn't make sense, but maybe magento wanted the messages at a special place. So this is no real bug, just a side effect if you use the contact form in a place it isn't standardly implemented (but intended!) for.